# Botbuilder: prompt don't wait user input

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, botframework

I'm learn botbuilder and need to make WaterfallDialog. Steps in WaterfallDialog works, but prompts don't wait for user input

```
async beginDialog(dc: DialogContext): Promise<DialogTurnResult<any>> {
        dc.dialogs.add(new WaterfallDialog('start', [
            async (step) => {
                // Ask user their name
                return await step.prompt('namePrompt', `What's your name?`, ['yes', 'no']);
            },
            async (step) => {
                // Remember the users answer
                step.values['name'] = step.result;

                // Ask user their age.
                return await step.prompt('agePrompt', `Hi ${step.values['name']}. How old are you?`);
            },
            async (step) => {
                // Remember the users answer
                step.values['age'] = step.result;

                // End the component and return the completed profile.
                return await step.endDialog(step.values);
            }
        ]));

        dc.dialogs.add(new TextPrompt('namePrompt'));
        dc.dialogs.add(new NumberPrompt('agePrompt'));

        return await dc.beginDialog(this.initialDialogId);
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If structured correctly, waterfall steps should wait for user input by default, unless interrupted by some other recognized command (such as a help or cancel command). Here is the [typescript waterfall dialog](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/typescript_nodejs/05.multi-turn-prompt) sample. You may wish to try using this sample as a model.